# passing a multidimensional array from controller to view in Codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a function `test` that would be used for several buildings types but I can't get the variables to be passed into the View.

Controller code:

```
public function index($data = NULL){
   $data1 = $this->test('hotel');
   $data2 = $this->test('restaurant');
   $data = array_merge($data1,$data2);
   $this->load->view('templates/default',$data); 
}

public function test($building_type){
   $data[$building_type]['title'] = 'this is a title for '.$building_type;
   for ($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) {
       $data[$building_type][$i] = $building_type.' button';
   }
   $data['building_type_array'] = ['hotel', 'restaurant'];       
   return $data;
}
```

View code:

```
foreach ($building_type_array as $value) {
    echo $value;           // echoes 'hotel' and 'restaurant'
    echo $value['title'];  // throws 'Illegal string offset'
    echo $value[3];        // echoes the 4th letter of 'hotEl' and 'resTaurant'
}
echo $building_type['title']; // Throws  'Undefined variable: building_type'

echo $hotel['title'];         // echoes 'this is a title for hotel'
echo $hotel[3];               // echoes 'hotel button'
```

The first four `echo` are attempts that do not give the expected result. The last two `echo` of the `View` give the expected result but I would like to use a generic variable to avoid writing `$hotel['title']`, `$restaurant['title']` ... for each building type.

Comment: You've shown the results, which are exactly as programmed.  Please explain *your* expected results.  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

Controller:

```
public function index($data = NULL) {
   $data['building_types']['hotel'] = $this->test('hotel');
   $data['building_types']['restaurant'] = $this->test('restaurant');

   $this->load->view('templates/default', $data); 
}
```

View:

```
foreach ($building_types as $building) {

    foreach ($building as $value) {
        echo $value;   // whatever
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know if i understand you, but i understand that you have an array
like

```
$m_array = //come from model
array(
     array(
          'title' => 'title',
          '1'     => 'value1',
          '2'     => 'value2',
          '3'     => 'value3'
     ),
    array(
          'title' => 'title2',
          '1'     => 'value1-2',
          '2'     => 'value2-2',
          '3'     => 'value3-2'
     ),
    array(
          'title' => 'title3',
          '1'     => 'value1-3',
          '2'     => 'value2-3',
          '3'     => array('one' => 'v-one', 'two' => 'v-two')
     ),
     //etc
    );
```

in your view

```
foreach($m_array as $item => $value){
    if( is_array($value)){
        foreach($value as $row => $value2){
            echo "<td>$item</td>";
            echo "<td>$row</td>";
            echo "<td>$value2</td>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<td>$item</td>";
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
        echo "<td>-</td>";
    }
}
```